Can I use @Body on a service/provider constructor?
I know you can use inject request in a service but can I use the @Body or @Header with class data validation like you would in a controller? I couldn't find any docs on this.

No. Those are only for route handlers in the controller. They're so that Nest knows what to pass to the route handler from the location where it transitions from internal framework code to "external" dev written code.
